# Zk get value of child component mvvm

Tags: mvvm, zk

Include component value showing null Not binding.

```
<window id="win" width="100%" border="normal" height="100%"
    apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" validationMessages="@id('vmsgs')"
    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.customer.portal.controller.MotorQuotationViewModel')">

<row>
     <include src="basicInfo.zul"></include>
</row>
<row>
     <button id="btnCalculatePremium"
                        onClick="@command('calculatePremium')" />
</row>
```

basicInfo.zul

```
<window id="win" width="100%" border="normal" height="100%"
        apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" validationMessages="@id('vmsgs')"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.customer.portal.controller.BaseController')">
        <grid>
            <rows>
                <row>
                    <label id="lblBasicInfo"></label>
                </row>
                <row id="rowIdType">
                    <label id="lblIdType"></label>
                    <textbox id="txtIdType" inplace="true"
                        value="@bind(vm.riskWebVO.VName)" constraint="no empty" />
                </row>
</rows>
</grid>
</window>
```

Main View Model

```
public class MotorQuotationViewModel extends BaseController {

    public void calculatePremium() {
logger.info(riskWebVO.getVName());//Showing null

}
public UwmtRiskWebVO getRiskWebVO() {
        return riskWebVO;
    }

    public void setRiskWebVO(UwmtRiskWebVO riskWebVO) {
        this.riskWebVO = riskWebVO;
    }

}
```

Child view model

```
    public class BaseController extends SelectorComposer<Component>{ 
        protected UwmtRiskWebVO riskWebVO = new UwmtRiskWebVO();
    public UwmtRiskWebVO getRiskWebVO() {
            return riskWebVO;
        }

        public void setRiskWebVO(UwmtRiskWebVO riskWebVO) {
            this.riskWebVO = riskWebVO;
        }

    }
```

When I'm getting value of main view model it's binding the values but when i'm trying to get the values of include components its showing null.

Answer (score 2):

### Possible problem :

Cause you speak of `null` and not `NullPointerException` I assume that when you create the new like your did, your name is not set.

```
protected UwmtRiskWebVO riskWebVO = new UwmtRiskWebVO();
```

### Second some tuning :

Do you work MVVM or MVC, but make a choice. You <del>shouldn't</del> can't `extends SelectorComposer<Component>` and then appplying the `BindCoomposer` in the zul.

### Tweaking :

While your `MotorQuotationViewModel` extends the `BaseController` you don't have to set the `BaseController` in the `basicInfo.zul` cause everyting inside the include will listen to the VM.

### Duplicated names :

With the section tweaking read, you now understand that you called your vm's twice `vm`.  how are you sure witch VM to take?
Take attention to the names what you set even in the includes.

Comment: I manage to get the child components with include.getfellow();